# Asymptotics of the Bessel function $J_\nu(z)$ for $\nu \to \infty$ starting from complex contour representation.

Tags: asymptotics, complex-integration, bessel-functions

Asymptotic behavior of the Bessel function $J_\nu$ as $\nu \to \infty$ is given by
$$
J_\nu(z) = \frac 1 {\sqrt {2 \pi}} \left( \frac {e z} {2 \nu} \right)^\nu \left( \nu^{-1/2} - \frac {3 z^2 + 1} {12} \nu^{-3/2} + O(\nu^{-5/2}) \right).
$$
[This post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3342578/what-is-the-error-of-asymptotic-relation-of-large-order-behavior-of-bessel-funct?rq=1) very nicely shows how to derive this from the integral representation of the Bessel 
function on the real axes
$$
J_\nu(z) =\frac {z^\nu} {2^\nu \sqrt \pi \, \Gamma {\left( \nu + \frac 1 2 \right)}} \int_{-1}^1 (1 - t^2)^{\nu - 1/2} \cos z t \, dt.
$$
Is there a way to obtain the same expansion from the integral representation in the complex plane
$$
J_\nu (z) = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{\mathcal C} e^{z \sinh t - \nu t} dt~?
$$
Here the contour $\mathcal C$ goes from $u_x \to \infty$ and $u_y = -\pi$, 
continues to $u_x \to -\infty$ and $u_y = 0$ and finally returns to $u_x \to \infty$ and $u_y = \pi$.

How would one approach constructing this expansion here without returning to the real axes integral representation? Can one use something like a saddle point method or Watson's lemma or something like that? This is usually done for obtaining the $z\to \infty$ expansion.

If this is for some reason a particularly bad approach, or not possible, 
I'd be interested in knowing the reasons why?

Comment: One normally uses this integral representation to derive the large-$\nu$ asymptotics of $J_\nu(\nu z)$ (Debye expansions).

Comment: Right, there the path seems a bit more clearer since one has saddles etc, and so the standard methods seem to work.