# Asymptotic expansion of Integral using Steepest Descent

Tags: definite-integrals, asymptotics

Can anyone help me to find the asymptotic expansion using Method of Steepest decent?
I have just started learning this method.

$I =\displaystyle{\int_0^{\pi}\cos nt e^{ia\cos t}~dt}$
$a$ is a large parameter,  $n$ here is an integer

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by help? Where have you got stuck when using this method?

Comment: The steps will be essentially the same as [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3721702). To obtain the leading term, find the steepest descent directions $e^{i \phi}$ at the endpoints, take $t = t_0 + e^{i \phi} \xi$ and expand $i \cos t$ to second order for small $\xi$.

Comment: @Maxim Thanks!, I tried your what you suggested since the stationary point is at t=0 I guess I can approximate it using t=(1+i)s, a straight line near t=0 , I expanded cosine in the exponent and cos(nt) till second order, this gives me exp(s^2) integral, which by rotating the contour I converted to a gaussian, but I am not getting the answer as given in the book. Any suggestions here? Sorry if its too trivial, I am absolutely new to this stuff and its not a part of any of my courses, so I only have myself for help. Answer:  $\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{\sqrt{2n}}(\frac{iea}{2n})^n$

Comment: The answer you have is for [large natural $n$ and fixed $a$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3343034). You might want to start with the simpler case of large $a$ and fixed $n$, as in your question. Draw the region $\{t: \operatorname {Re}(i \cos t) < 0\}$ and consider why you can't take $t = e^{\pi i/4} \xi$ or $t = e^{3 \pi i/4} \xi$ or $t = e^{-3 \pi i/4} \xi$ with $\xi > 0$ near $t = 0$.

Comment: The real part of ia$\cos(t)$ for $t= u + iv$ comes out to be -$(\sin u\sinh v)$ as long as both u and v are of the same sign, the curve remains a steepest descent curve, so what could be wrong with t= (1+i)s? for getting a gaussian, it seems I need to take (1-i)s. For a fixed and n being large, I guess I need to treat cos(nt) as  Re exp( i nt)

Comment: $\operatorname {Re}(i \cos(u + i v)) \neq -\sin u \sinh v$. It's clear that the integral of $e^{a \xi^2}$ with real $\xi$ which you've obtained can't be approximated by restricting the integration range to a small interval near $\xi = 0$. But you do have to consider the region $D = \{t: \operatorname {Re}(i \cos t) < 0\}$ to explain why $t = e^{3 \pi i/4} \xi$ doesn't work (because we want the whole contour, with the exception of a finite number of points, to lie in $D$ to be able to restrict the integration range to the vicinity of those points).