# Full asymptotic expansion of Integral using Steepest descent

Tags: definite-integrals, asymptotics

How do I find the full asymptotic expansion of the following integral using steepest decent-? I came across this integral while working through the book on Mathematical Methods by Bender.

$$I=\int_0^1t^{\alpha}e^{ixt^3}dt$$.

to do this using Steepest descent, we have to deform the contour from $t= 0$ to $t= 1$ in the real part of t, in complex $t$ plane, into two contours of steepest descent joined by a contour with vanishing contribution-
Now,
$a(t) = it^3$,
let $t = $u + i$v$,
cubing $t$ we get-
$a(t) = i(u^3- 3uv^2) - (3u^2v- v^3)$
for $t=0$, it's easy to see, $u=\sqrt3$, to get steepest descent contour, it's also not too hard to use laplace integral for the contour-
$t= v( i + \sqrt(3))$,  $0<=v<\infty$.
But for $t= 1$, the contour itself is very messy and so is the integral along the contour through $t =1$.
Any suggestions on how to proceed further? also, any idea on one would proceed, if integrated had higher powers of $t$ like- $t^5$?
Thanks!

Comment: It is sufficient to take a contour $\gamma$ which approaches $0$ and $1$ in the steepest descent direction (and s.t. $\operatorname {Re}(i t^3) < 0$ on $\gamma \setminus \{0, 1\}$). Further, then we need to consider only an arbitrarily small part of $\gamma$ near the endpoints. For the part near $1$, we can take $t = (1 + i \xi)^{1/3}$. The factor that depends on $\xi$ will be $(1 + i \xi)^p e^{-x \xi}$. Expanding the binomial gives a complete asymptotic series.