# Asymptotics of the Bessel function

Tags: asymptotics, bessel-functions

Suppose I have an $n$-order Bessel function: $J_{n}\left(x\right)=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi}\cos\left(nt-x\sin t\right)dt$

I can easily calculate the asymptotics for $x\gg n$. To do this, I will use the stationary phase method. But what should I do if $n\gg x$ ? How to calculate the asymptotics in this case? My intuition tells me that it is necessary to integrate in parts in some way

Comment: Can't you just do the same thing?

Comment: Are you forced to start with the integral representation in OP? If not, starting with [equation 10.9.4](https://dlmf.nist.gov/10.9): $J_\nu(x)=[\dots]\int\limits_0^\pi dt \ \cos(x\cos t)\sin^{2\nu}t$ and using Laplace's method seems simplest.

Comment: Yet easier: the first term of the power series for $J_n(x)$ (deducible from the given intrep).

Comment: Also see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3343034).